# Very different results with nautilus and du

Tags: linux, debian, disk-usage

I use Debian 9.4.

When I check the size of the folder using right click -> properties, it shows that the size of the folder is 32 GB,

When I do `du -s --block-size=1G ./ATemp` it shows the size is 22 GB.

How to explain the difference in 10GB?

Comment: Do you have sparse files in your directory?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, I don't